# Bower, Grunt, Bootstrap, Jquery and JavaScript Errors

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, bower

I'm new to Bower and Grunt, and am trying to integrate it into my workflow.

I've install Bootstrap with Bower, and I've installed the grunt-bower-concat grunt task for concatenating my Bower components and deploying them a single js / css file in my src folder.

All this works; however, after referencing my generated _bower.js, I see a 'Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery' in the console. Looking at the code in question, I can see that it's complaining because typeof(jQuery) === undefined.

As best as I can tell, jQuery has been defined earlier in this file - so I'm not sure why it's complaining.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is because in your concatenation, You did not follow the order of jQuery and Bootstrap. In the `gruntfile.js`, put jQuery before the bootstrap js file as jQuery is bootstrap's dependency!

Comment: Thanks Farzad YZ! I manually specified the components I wished to be included in the concatenation, and I specified jquery as a bootstrap dependency, and all appears well now! I'm confused why the dependencies / ordering weren't self-evident from the components themselves though.

Comment: Also @FarzadYZ, if you post you comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You had to manually specify the order of concatenation in grunt-bower-concat? That sounds like there's something else going on. Can you post up at least your Gruntfile for me to see?

Answer (score 0):

Try to be aware of dependencies and order of your `js` files you provide for uglify.

Bootstrap's js file needs jQuery as it's dependency so put the `jQuery.js` before `bootstrap.js`. With this solution you will solve the issue of ####Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery####.
In the `gruntfile.js`, put jQuery before the bootstrap js file as jQuery is bootstrap's dependency!

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to integrating all these elements together, I'd think the biggest potential issues you'd face are setting up your Gruntfile and deciding which elements you're piping through Bower and which are still in your project's src somewhere.

I actually set up a [Repo](https://github.com/suzumakes/static-boilerplate) specifically for getting into working with Bower, Grunt, and Bootstrap.